# From Laravel Query Builder to Eloquent with request: where()->orWhere()->get()

Tags: eloquent

Is it possible to write this query with Eloquent Builder ?

```
$transactions = Transaction::where('client_id', $this->id)
                             ->orWhere('supplier_id', $this->id)
                             ->get();
```

Comment: Can't you simply do this? DB::table('transaction')->where('client_id', $this->id)
                             ->orWhere('supplier_id', $this->id)
                             ->get();

Comment: I can, but it's still Query Builder, not Eloquent Builder.